# Getting error when running npm-run after git merging conflicts

Tags: webpack, npm-run

I get the following error when I run npm run watch/npm run dev after a git merge where I resolved some conflicts manually:

> /Users/Julia/sites/kickback/webpack.mix.js:19 <<<<<<< HEAD ^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <<
>       at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
>       at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
>       at Module._compile (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
>       at require (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
>       at Object. (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:12:1)
>       at Module._compile (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
>       at require (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
>       at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:116:13)
>       at requireConfig (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:118:6)
>       at /Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:125:17
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at module.exports (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:123:15)
>       at yargs.parse (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45)
>       at Object.parse (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:567:18)
>       at /Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
>       at Object. (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:365:3)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
>       at Object. (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:156:2)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js

After resolving all conflicts now I get the following error:

```
./resources/assets/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!./resources/assets/sass/main.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/tailwind.config.js:511
=======
   ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at /Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js:54:83
    at /Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:32:20
    at LazyResult.run (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:295:14)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:208:26)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:14)
    at /Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:250:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at LazyResult.async (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:246:23)
    at LazyResult.then (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:127:17)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (/Users/Julia/sites/kickback/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js:142:8)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss 2:14-208
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not resolved all issues, solve all merge issues and it should be ok.